# premake external configuration for library

Tags: premake

I'm working on changing all makefiles to use premake for my project.

Since it has many other external libraries using other configuraton tools like autotools, I decided just to use its own Makefile rather than making makeifle by premake for some libraries. I understand "kind : Makefile" is available for what I am going to do.

The problem is that autotools ./configure command should be preceded, but I don't know how to do it by premake. Can anybody suggest to how to deal with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Lua's [os.execute()](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.2.html) to call external commands.

```
os.setcwd("path/to/project")
os.execute("./configure")
```

Does that do what you need?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I'm looking for. Premake is awesome anyway. I appreciate it.